# How to iterate a list without inserting the new word to list?

Tags: list, python-3.x, loops, iteration

I understand how to index a word in a given list, but if given a set list and a word not in the list, how do I find the index position of the new word without appending or inserting the new word to the sorted list?

For example:
def find_insert_position: 
    a_list = ['Bird', 'Dog', 'Alligator']
    new_animal = 'Cow'

Without altering the list, how would I determine where the new word would be inserted within a sorted list?  So that if you entered the new word, the list would stat in alphabetical order.  Keep in mind this is a given list and word, so I would not know any of the words before hand. I am using Python3.

Comment: You realise in your example there's nowhere you could insert "Cow" to make that list alphabetical, right?

Comment: @JonClements It's a homework assignment. We are to return the index of a given name within a given list.  if the word is not in the list, we must determine where the word would be inserted without changing its order.  I know in python we can sort lists to make them alphabetical but I'm not sure how to find the position of a word if I am not allowed to add it to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is acceptable to add the word to *another litst* without altering the original list, then you can try this:

```
def find_insert_position(lst, word):
    new_lst = lst[:]    # make a copy of the list so you don't modify the original
    new_lst.append(word)    # add word to lst
    sorted_lst = sorted(new_lst) 
    return sorted_lst.index(word)    # return 0-based position of word in  sorted list

a_list = ['Bird', 'Dog', 'Alligator']
new_animal = 'Cow'

print(find_insert_position(a_list, new_animal))
```

Comment: I thought of doing this, I mean it doesn't say NOT to make a new list. Lol. Thanks you!!  I had to modify it to fit all the possible conditions of the spec but it passed the test. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable counter to 0
Loop through each item inthe wordlist and compare each word in the list with the given list
If the given word is greater than the item in list then increment the counter

So when you are out of the loop, counter value is the index you are looking for.

You can convert this to code.

Comment: I think a classmate of mine was trying to explain to do it this way but I must have been doing something wrong because I could not get it to work for me.